# multithread Error .net Parallel.For

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.for

I have to caculate distances among about 26,000 companies, and to find the median of all the distances. However, the program throw the exception below:

```
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, Action`2 body)
at DataHelper.FindMediumBase.CountDistancesPerKilometer()
```

This is my program:

```
protected void CountDistancesPerKilometer()
{
    try
    {
        int EnterprisesCount = enterprises.Count;
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        Parallel.For(0, enterprises.Count, (i, loopStateOut) =>
        {
            Enterprise eOut = enterprises.ElementAt(i);
            for (int j = i + 1; j < enterprises.Count; j++)
            {
                Enterprise eIn = enterprises.ElementAt(j);
                double distance = Math.Sqrt((eOut.Point.X - eIn.Point.X) * (eOut.Point.X - eIn.Point.X) +
                                            (eOut.Point.Y - eIn.Point.Y) * (eOut.Point.Y - eIn.Point.Y)) / 1000;

                if (0 == distance)
                    continue;
                else
                    DistanceFiles[(int)distance].FileRowCount++;
            }
        });
        watch.Stop();
        System.Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedTicks);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.WriteError(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

PS:

```
enterprises: List<Enterprise>
DistanceFiles : ConcurrentDictionary<int, DistanceFile>
```

Comment: `DistanceFiles[(int)distance].FileRowCount++;` - Are you sure `distance` is an existing key in the dictionary?

Comment: What is `DistanceFiles`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko At the bottom of the question: `ConcurrentDictionary<int, DistanceFile>`

Comment: Do you have an exception on *sequential version* of your code (i.e. `Parallel.For` changed into `for(...)`)

Comment: while, I remember the max distance is less than 5000 kilometers, but I will try to make the dictionary larger @YuvalItzchakov

Comment: It doesn't throw excption if I use for() {}, but it will take more than 16 hours to finish the caculating, so I use Parallel.For. but now I can't find the possible reasons@DmitryBychenko

Comment: @mzl9039 plaease add full exception info including inner exception details . Change Log.WriteError(ex.StackTrace); to the Log.WriteError(ex.ToString()); or Log.WriteError(ex.Message); and add new results to the quetion.

Comment: It would take 16 hours? I dont see anything here that indicates that should take that long! However, you could be run into an issue that you may need to lock your distancefiles update.. Although, i dont see what youve defined that as

Comment: there are about 26,000 companies, so I have to caculate 26000 * 25999 / 2 distances, it takes a lot of time@BugFinder

Answer (score 0):

You call [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Item`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267253(v=vs.110).aspx) which can throw [`KeyNotFoundException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.keynotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx) if the property is retrieved and key does not exist in the collection.

Change you code to ensure that elements are exist in the dictionary:

```
if (0 == distance)
    continue;
else
{
    if(!DistanceFiles.ContainsKey((int)distance))
    {
        var distanceFile = GetDistanceFile(); // retrieve or create new instance of tDistanceFile here
        DistanceFiles,Add((int)distance, distanceFile);
    }
    DistanceFiles[(int)distance].FileRowCount++;
}
```

Comment: Well, I can't ensure all the positions of the companies are correct, so your answer are possibly the correct reason! I will try it, and thanks a lot !!!@Vadim Martynov